# User Interface file compilation using OSGeo4W shell during qgis plugin creation

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, osgeo4w

I am trying to build a plugin in Qgis2.6 using plugin builder. And as a part of the same, I tried compiling the .ui and .qrc file using OSGeo4W shell. It is showing an error during compilation in OSGeo4W shell. Please help me how to compile the ui as well as qrc file using OSGeo4W shell or reply me where I am wrong from the below attached error. I am new in QGis plugin creation. The plugin contents inside the folder also attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wrap they file name in quotes: "CSV Export.py" etc

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the error disappears after wrapping the file name in quotes.But I wonder last time when I created I didn't wrap the filename in quotes but the compilation was successful.

Comment: Avoid blank spaces in (Python) file names. It doesn't help you and will bring you troubles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will write a quick explanation of the **pyuic4** and **pyrcc4** commands for future reference. Most tutorials simply tell you to copy some code, but no one explains exactly what you are about to do. It is quite simple actually, but beginners might still struggle with it.

The Plugin Builder generates a fairly 'empty' plugin template. The two files that are of interest to us, as we need to convert them to Python files manually, are the GUI file (.**ui**) and the resource file (.**qrc**).

Let us assume my Plugin Builder leaves me with the following files when creating a template for a plugin that I named Color Changer: *color_changer_dialog_base.ui* and *resources.qrc*.

Now, to convert these files to Python (.**py**) files we need to move to a console (for example, the **OSGeo4W Shell**).

The syntax for the GUI conversion is:
pyuic4 -o *nameOfTheFileWeWantToCreate*.py *nameOfOurExistingFile*.ui

As in:

```
pyuic4 -o color_changer_dialog_base.py color_changer_dialog_base.ui
```

And the syntax for the resource file is:
   pyrcc4 -o *nameOfTheFileWeWantToCreate*.py *nameOfOurExistingFile*.qrc

As in:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

Of course, all rules that generally apply in GIS or programming should be considered. In your case, consider not using blank spaces in file names.

So, this:
[image: before conversion]

through this:
[image: OSGeo4W Shell]

will become this:
[image: after conversion]

Comment: Thank you so much BritishSteel for your good explanation.Really your explanation helps me understanding a lot.

Comment: Would be nice to have this updated for QGIS 3, pyuic5 and pyrcc5;